# Implementing autocomplete in android based on django model

Tags: android, python, django, autocomplete

I am trying to create an autocomplete box in my android app that is powered by a Django backend. I have a model in Django where I have a lot of rows (~5k). I want to be able to do an autocomplete search in my android app powered by this backend based on the name(field in a row). What is the best way to do this?

Some details-
The details in rows might be changed or altered from time to time.
New row additions will be much more frequent.

I have thought about sending a queryset (With all objects when user opens an app) would be slow and consume a lot of data.

I am not sure how to make requests continuously and handle response in time for autocomplete box to populate without overloading the server.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: use ajax and start to make suggestions after 3 chars with a list of max 20 suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make an API, which will be called periodically by android application, which will provide all the updated data from Database. The input of the API will be the last API calling time. So the API will provide updated objects from that datetime. To do that, you need to add a field in your model i.e:

```
class YourModel(models.Model):
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    # Rest of the fields.
```

So when you hit the API with last api call time, you will run this query in backend:

```
query = YourModel.objects.filter(last_updated__gte = last_api_call_time)
```

Then store all the updated data in android app's database. Then call the search within db of android app. The advantage of doing it is that you don't need to call API every time someone types words in searchbox of your app.